# Faster Angular Tree Menu

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wrote a snippet of code in angular that creates a tree menu out of JSON:

```
<!-- Tree Menu Template-->
<script type="text/ng-template"  id="tree_item_renderer.html">
    <a href="{{data.url}}" ng-click="toggleHideChildren(data)">
    <i ng-class="{'fa fa-chevron-circle-right':!data.expanded, 
                  'fa fa-chevron-circle-down':  data.expanded}" ng-show="data.nodes"></i> {{data.name}}
    </a>
    <div class="treeItem" ng-repeat="data in data.nodes" ng-include="'tree_item_renderer.html'" ng-hide="data.hidden" ng-init="data.hidden=true"></div>
</script>
<!-- End Tree Menu Template-->

<!-- Tree Menu -->
<div class="row top-buffer">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="treeRoot" ng-repeat="data in tree" ng-include="'tree_item_renderer.html'"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- End Tree Menu -->
```

Sample tree menu:

```
$scope.tree = {"name":"General", "nodes": [
    {"name":"Summary", "url":"#/general/summary"},

    {"name":"A Stats", "nodes": [
        {"name":"Sub 1"},
        {"name":"Sub 2"}
    ]},  

    {"name":"B Stats"}
]}
```

This code works fine. However, once my tree menu has several hundred items in it, my angular app takes longer and longer to load (> 5 seconds). I suspect this is because of the large amounts of `ng-repeat` and `ng-includes` going on here.

Is there a faster way I can do this using angular features? Or do I have to ditch angular to get the speed gains?

Comment: you could generate the html from the menu object elsewhere and simply plug it in, because the ng-include is not as fast. just a thought

Comment: I ended up employing a lazy-loading technique so that the lop level tree nodes load quickly, and sub nodes are only loaded when needed

Comment: would be nice if you could share what you did.